# Migrating to CocoaPods 1.1.1 with WatchKit Extension

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

I am trying to migrate to the latest version of CocoaPods from 0.39. Here is my original podfile:

```
platform :ios, '10.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'MyApp' do
    pod 'SwiftyJSON'
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0'
    pod 'AlamofireImage', '~> 3.1'
end

target 'MyAppWatchKitApp' do

end

target 'MyAppWatchKitApp Extension' do

end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.0'
    end
  end
end
```

After reading the [CocoaPods 1.0 Migration Guide](http://blog.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-1.0-Migration-Guide/) and [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37684343/migrating-to-cocoapods-1-0-1) I tried updating my podfile:

```
platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'MyApp' do
    use_frameworks!

    pod 'SwiftyJSON'
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0'
    pod 'AlamofireImage', '~> 3.1'

    target 'MyAppWatchKitApp' do

    end

    target 'MyAppWatchKitApp Extension' do

    end

end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.0'
    end
  end
end
```

Saving the podfile, running `pod update` in Terminal, then opening and building the project, I see the following error (client name censored, replace with "MyApp" to match pod files above):

[image: Screenshot of error]

Other things I've tried:

- Doing a `pod install` in addition to `pod update`
- Deleting derived data

I have some good experience with Swift and Xcode but pods are still relatively new to me. Maybe I'm missing something very basic. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

Add this line to your post install step in the Podfile.
 **config.build_settings['ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH'] = 'NO'**

Comment: Thank you for your response. I put your code immediately after the line `config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.0'` in the podfile, then ran `pod install` and `pod update`, cleaned and build my project, but still see the same error.