# Cocoa pod v0.39.0 not working with Xcode 8

Tags: xcode, terminal, cocoapods, podspec, cocoapods-0.39.0

My current project using cocoa pods of version 0.39.1, and my current pod version in my system is 1.1.1, so when i try to install the cocoa pods in my project path, it gave me warning saying

[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: [!] Unsupported options `{:exclusive=>true}` for target `Xxx Xxx XxxxTests`..

so i have uninstalled pod v1.1.1 and installed 0.39.1. Now when i run install command i get another warning

[!] The `master` repo requires CocoaPods 1.0.0 - (currently using 0.39.0) Update Cocoapods, or checkout the appropriate tag in the repo.

i'm aware that **Xcode 8: Only works with CocoaPods 1.1.0**

Should i update my project pod file to latest pod version or should i work with lower version of xcode so it supports v0.39.0

Comment: Share your podfile code

Answer (score 0):

I recently completed a project where I had to migrate a dozen or so (private) Cocoapods from 0.39 up to 1.1.X.

It's actually not that hard, once you get the hang of it (and, at least in my case, the Podfile I put together for 1.1.X continued to work the occasional times I had to drop back down to Pods 0.39)

As you've discovered, you do need to remove "`:exclusive => true`" and "`link_with`" (which gets replaced with `abstract_target`).  More information can be found in this [Pods migration guide](http://blog.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-1.0-Migration-Guide/). [Here is another "mini" example](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4706).

And other people [have asked related questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37684343/migrating-to-cocoapods-1-0-1) before.  My recommendation is to go up to Xcode 8, otherwise you'll won't be able to do `pod update` and keep up to date with the latest changes in the Pods you're trying to leverage in your code.